Vue.js - how to fix bind `:=` syntax error?
In my Vue.js project (latest version) this makes error:
<script setup>
let imageInfo = {
    src: "https:/myImg.jpg",
    alt: "my img",
    width: 400
};
</script>

<template>
    <img :="imageInfo">
</template>

it does not likes := syntax. error msg is:
'imageInfo' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars.
I've disabled this error in .eslintrc.js:
"no-unused-vars": "off"
but it does not helps.
If I use imageInfo inside <script>, like this console.log(imageInfo) then error disappears.
Please help me.

seems an eslint error in VUE files, doesn't relate to vue itself

@AlexanderNenashev project is absolutely new, just created

If "no-unused-vars": "off" doesn't work this potentially means that eslint config isn't applied for some reason, this needs to be verified by trying to change other rules. The question doesn't make sense in general as it's specific to project template you use and eslint specifically, not vue

Edit: the syntax does actually work, but TS shows a warning. This might be a problem with the vue tools though, you should probably create an issue over here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues

You can't use the shorthand v-bind when binding multiple attributes. To bind multiple attributes you should use the full v-bind:
<script setup>
let imageInfo = {
    src: "https:/myImg.jpg",
    alt: "my img",
    width: 400
};
</script>

<template>
    <img v-bind="imageInfo">
</template>


I'm just watching the tutorial on YouTube and this gay has no errors with := syntax (time 46:30): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgWZLS75Nmo&t=2794s

@DevMis yeah it somehow seems valid but not recognized. You should probably create a bug report on GitHub

@Jonathan As said, := is supported, this is likely recent addition that hasn't been properly documented, somewhere around 3.3-3.4. Also it's eslint error, not ts

Vue tools lag behind Vue. For example many people including me were waiting for Vue for VSCode to support property shortcut syntax :prop (instead of :prop="prop"), so you could use v-bind:
<script setup>
let imageInfo = {
    src: "https:/myImg.jpg",
    alt: "my img",
    width: 400
};
</script>

<template>
    <img v-bind="imageInfo">
</template>


I'm just watching the tutorial on YouTube and this gay has no errors with := syntax (time 46:30): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgWZLS75Nmo&t=2794s

@DevMis damn, you are right, it works

There is an issue on GitHub.com
